# Chart.JS fixing maximum and minumum to a location on screen

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I am working with chart. js and need to fix the minimum and maximum on the yAxis on the screen, meaning that, for instance, the maximum value is always on the exact same spot where it would be with other data inputs/values.

For example, when the maximum value on the array is 5, it creates a yAxis where the maximum level is 5 and places the line(line graph/chart) to that location, but when the maximum value in a New data array is 2000, then instead of jumping to 2000 on the yAxis, the chart will place the 2000 value to the exact same spot where the number 5 was, meaning, the maximum spot is fixed visually, but not in terms of data values, the same with minimum.

At the same time the yAxis must be dynamic/flexible, so when one data array inserts numbers that are, for example, between 10 to 0, it places the line chart to an area that is visually preferred to be always on the same spot when the chart is updated with data values between 1000 to 0 or 1000 to 900 instead of 10 to 0.

Basically, how to place the line chart always to the same spot area, but insert different values.

Need to have the line maximum and minimum spot always in the same place regardless of the data values, while the line in between changes shape.

The current chart has always 1 line on a chart that is updated with different values.

Is this to be most likely accomplished with mix and max points while reading the min and max values from the data array, or it is something entirely else?

```
var data1 = [ 1, 9, 12, 3, 15, 8, 2, -5, 3, 4,
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type : 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data : {
            labels : [ '', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', '' ],
            datasets : [ {
                label : 'My dataset',
                borderWidth : 3,
                borderColor : 'rgb(255,0, 0)',
                data : data1,
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options : {
            elements : {
                point : {
                    radius : 3
                }
            },
            legend : {
                labels : {
                    fontColor : "white",
                    fontSize : 18
                }
            },
            scales : {
                yAxes : [ {
                    ticks : {
                        beginAtZero : false,
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false,
                        drawBorder : false,
                    }
                } ],
                xAxes : [ {
                    ticks : {
                        fontColor : "white",
                        fontSize : 14,
                        beginAtZero : 0,
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false,
                    }
                } ]
            },
            tooltips : {
                callbacks : {
                    label : function(tooltipItem) {
                        console.log(tooltipItem)
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });

    function updateChart() {
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = [ 800, 200, 900, 900, 100, 500, 200, 100, 200 ];
        chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = '#32a852';
        chart.update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy the chart

```html
myLineChart.destroy();
```

Now call the function

```html
updateChart()
```